# Matlab shapewrite: export point shapefile + set projection to WGS84

Tags: matlab, gis, map-projections

I need to export a point shapefile from Matlab, but I can't figure out how to set the coordinates to WGS84 (which is maybe the most common one) using `shapefile`. It seems to be a non-trivial task.

The command is:

```
Struct2GIS = struct('Geometry', 'Point',...
'OutputVariable1', num2cell(Var1), ...
'OutputVariable2', num2cell(Var2), ...
'OutputVariable3', num2cell(Var3),...
'OutputVariable4', num2cell(Var4),...
'X',num2cell(Lon),'Y', num2cell(Lat));

shapewrite(Struct2GIS,Filename)
```

Any ideas please?
thanks!

Comment: interesting thanks. Any ideas on how the following line would need to be for WGS84: GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

Comment: @OliverAmundsen can you please edit your question to include this line, and tell us what exactly what your input is, and what the desired result for that would be? Also, if possible, show us the code you already tried?

Comment: Done. The code above works perfectly and I'm able to open it in ArcGIS. But then I get the message that there is no projection..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work-around: before I load the shapefile into Arc, in ArcCatalog, I right click on the file name, select Properties and then I tell it what the Coordinate system is.  Less than ideal, but it works.